# Send bulk emails upon receiving an email from a specific address in Outlook or Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-filter

I want an filter or a rule that allows me to send bulk emails to around 200 recipients when an email is received from a specific address.  For example, when the email client receives an email From `test@gmail.com`, I want it to resend the email to all the people in my address book.

I tried to set rules in both Outlook and Thunderbird email clients, but the the only option I have is to "Forward", not to "Resend" or "Send" the email.  there is an additional problem that all recipients appear in the address list.  I want all addressees to be bcc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a rule to forward to a bcc'ed distribution list.

Edit 2015 02 23

While the above is technically true. It is not as simple as I thought. There is no bcc option in the dialog box for addresses when forwarding by rule. My version is 2010.

You can set a bcc in a rule with a run a script option rather than using the dialog box.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Forward_BCC_DL(item As Object)

Dim newForward As MailItem
Dim myRecipient As Recipient

If item.Class = olMail Then

    Set newForward = item.Forward

    Set myRecipient = newForward.Recipients.Add("Name of Distribution List with the quotes")
    myRecipient.Type = olBCC

    newForward.Recipients.ResolveAll
    newForward.Display  ' Comment out with a leading apostrophe once tested
    'newForward.Send    ' Remove leading apostrophe once tested

End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set newForward = Nothing
    Set myRecipient = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Forward_BCC_DL_Test()
' To test
'  open a message then run this code
Dim curritem As Object
Set curritem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
Forward_BCC_DL curritem
End Sub
```

If you are not familiar with VBA this will be helpful.

[Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx)

[How to use Outlook's VBA Editor](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/)

Edit 2015 02 23 - End

Edit 2015 02 24

It is probably better to create a distribution list as used above but this will slowly retrieve all contacts.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Forward_BCC_All(mail As MailItem)

    Dim ContactsFolder As folder
    Dim Contact As Object
    Dim objMail As MailItem
    'Dim j As Long
    Dim objRecip As Recipient

    Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)

    Set objMail = mail.Forward
    'j = 0

    For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items

        'j = j + 1

        With objMail
            'Debug.Print j & ": " & Contact
            Set objRecip = .Recipients.Add(Contact)
            objRecip.Type = olBCC
        End With

    Next

    'Debug.Print "Resolving contacts slowly"

    objMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
    objMail.Display

ExitRoutine:
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set ContactsFolder = Nothing
    Set Contact = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Forward_BCC_All_test()
Dim currItem As MailItem
Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
Forward_BCC_All currItem
End Sub
```

Edit 2015 02 24 - End

Comment: how could i forward to bcc'ed distribution list where the only option available that i can use in the rules is "forward it to people or distribution list"  ?

Comment: You should get the same dialog box as if you were forwarding manually. That dialog box has a BCC button.

Comment: i didn't see this option , could you post a screenshot ?